# error for tensor size speecht5 model-Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Expected size 16 but got size 256 for tensor number 1

Tags: text-to-speech, tensor

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/speecht5/modeling_speecht5.py in forward(self, input_values, speaker_embeddings)
700             speaker_embeddings = speaker_embeddings.expand(-1, inputs_embeds.size(1), -1)
701             speaker_embeddings = speaker_embeddings.repeat(inputs_embeds.size(0), 1, 1)
--> 702             inputs_embeds = torch.cat([inputs_embeds, speaker_embeddings], dim=-1)
703             inputs_embeds = nn.functional.relu(self.speaker_embeds_layer(inputs_embeds))
704

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Expected size 16 but got size 256 for tensor number 1 in the list.

Tried on custom dataset as well as https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i7I5pzBcU3WDFarDnzweIj4-sVVoIUFJ#scrollTo=87U167Vf7V5Q with dutch lanfuage dataset from https://huggingface.co/datasets/facebook/voxpopuli/viewer/cs/train?row=1. Getting the same error both in colab as well in jupiterlap